# Invalid argument: indices[207,1] = 1611 is not in [0, 240) - Tensorflow 2.x (Python)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm using a RNN **LSTM model** to classify personality types. I'm getting an unexpected indices error when I start to train the model. I tried to use some solutions using the tracebacks, but there is no information of this issue using TF 2.0.
I will leave my [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MTxv4sfntPL1AhrW2DlaQ7HRAUYDV5UN) If you'll like to have a look up.

**MODEL:**

```py
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim = 240, output_dim = 64)) # The maxlen of the training and validation data is 240.
model.add(keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(64)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

**Training the model:**

```py
fitModel = model.fit(train_data_padded, train_label_seq,
                     epochs = 10,
                     batch_size = 295, # The length of the data is 295
                     validation_data = (validation_padded, validation_label_seq),
                     verbose = 1)
```

**Traceback:**

```
Train on 236 samples, validate on 59 samples
Epoch 1/10
236/236 [==============================] - 0s 71us/sample
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-48497b2e653e> in <module>()
      3                                          batch_size = 295, #how many we will load it at once (number of samples per gradient)
      4                                          validation_data = (validation_padded, validation_label_seq), #(x_val, y_val) validation_padded, validation_label_seq
----> 5                      verbose = 1)

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  indices[207,1] = 1611 is not in [0, 240)
     [[node sequential_3/embedding_3/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-31-bd83004f8334>:5) ]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  indices[207,1] = 1611 is not in [0, 240)
     [[node sequential_3/embedding_3/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-31-bd83004f8334>:5) ]]
     [[VariableShape/_22]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_distributed_function_22239]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential_3/embedding_3/embedding_lookup:
 sequential_3/embedding_3/embedding_lookup/20179 (defined at /usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py:81)

Input Source operations connected to node sequential_3/embedding_3/embedding_lookup:
 sequential_3/embedding_3/embedding_lookup/20179 (defined at /usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py:81)

Function call stack:
distributed_function -> distributed_function
```

Comment: That you have an index with value 1161 means your vocabulary has more than 240 values, and that is the problem.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro you are right, the shape of the training data padded is (236, 240), so now I'm using 56,640 as input_dim. It woked, but I'm getting NaN values in the training summary.

Comment: E.g.: `0s 533us/sample - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00`

Comment: Have you tried `input_dim = 240 + 1`?

Comment: @Tyler傲来国主 new errors appear, now says `Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function`. I'll leave you the link If you want to check it out. I really don't know what I was doing wrong

Comment: @Tyler傲来国主 https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MTxv4sfntPL1AhrW2DlaQ7HRAUYDV5UN?usp=sharing

Comment: looks like your training goes well and you have an error on validation phase. Check validation_padded - there are should be no values exceeding 239 (because it is maximum permitted value for embedding layer). Don't change dimensions - they are correct

Answer (score 2):

Check for the maximum value using `pd.DataFrame(x_train).max()`

I got 32552, so just add 32552+1 as input_dim

```
i.e input_dim  = 32553
```

Answer (score 1):

The first arguments to the Embedding layer is the dictionary size, and not the max feature length

```
 model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(*try dictionary size here, output_dim = 64))
```

Comment: what dictionary size are you talking about?