# "Invalid argument: indices[0,0,0,0] = 30 is not in [0, 30)"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

**Error:**

```
InvalidArgumentError: indices[0,0,0,0] = 30 is not in [0, 30)
     [[{{node GatherV2}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

**History:**

I have a custom data loader for a `tf.keras` based U-Net for semantic segmentation, based on [this example](https://yann-leguilly.gitlab.io/post/2019-12-14-tensorflow-tfdata-segmentation/). It is written as follows:

```
def parse_image(img_path: str) -> dict:
    # read image
    image = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    #image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image)
    if xf == "png":
        image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels = 3)
    else:
        image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels = 3)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.uint8)
    #image = image[:, :, :-1]
    # read mask
    mask_path = tf.strings.regex_replace(img_path, "X", "y")
    mask_path = tf.strings.regex_replace(mask_path, "X." + xf, "y." + yf)
    mask = tf.io.read_file(mask_path)
    #mask = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(mask)
    mask = tf.image.decode_png(mask, channels = 1)
    #mask = mask[:, :, :-1]
    mask = tf.where(mask == 255, np.dtype("uint8").type(NoDataValue), mask)
    return {"image": image, "segmentation_mask": mask}

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(
    dir_tls(myear = year, dset = "X") + "/*." + xf, seed = zeed)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(parse_image)

val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(
    dir_tls(myear = year, dset = "X_val") + "/*." + xf, seed = zeed)
val_dataset = val_dataset.map(parse_image)

## data transformations--------------------------------------------------------
@tf.function
def normalise(input_image: tf.Tensor, input_mask: tf.Tensor) -> tuple:
    input_image = tf.cast(input_image, tf.float32) / 255.0
    return input_image, input_mask

@tf.function
def load_image_train(datapoint: dict) -> tuple:
    input_image = tf.image.resize(datapoint["image"], (imgr, imgc))
    input_mask = tf.image.resize(datapoint["segmentation_mask"], (imgr, imgc))
    if tf.random.uniform(()) > 0.5:
        input_image = tf.image.flip_left_right(input_image)
        input_mask = tf.image.flip_left_right(input_mask)
    input_image, input_mask = normalise(input_image, input_mask)
    return input_image, input_mask

@tf.function
def load_image_test(datapoint: dict) -> tuple:
    input_image = tf.image.resize(datapoint["image"], (imgr, imgc))
    input_mask = tf.image.resize(datapoint["segmentation_mask"], (imgr, imgc))
    input_image, input_mask = normalise(input_image, input_mask)
    return input_image, input_mask

## create datasets-------------------------------------------------------------
buff_size = 1000
dataset = {"train": train_dataset, "val": val_dataset}
# -- Train Dataset --#
dataset["train"] = dataset["train"]\
    .map(load_image_train, num_parallel_calls = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
dataset["train"] = dataset["train"].shuffle(buffer_size = buff_size,
                                            seed = zeed)
dataset["train"] = dataset["train"].repeat()
dataset["train"] = dataset["train"].batch(bs)
dataset["train"] = dataset["train"].prefetch(buffer_size = AUTOTUNE)
#-- Validation Dataset --#
dataset["val"] = dataset["val"].map(load_image_test)
dataset["val"] = dataset["val"].repeat()
dataset["val"] = dataset["val"].batch(bs)
dataset["val"] = dataset["val"].prefetch(buffer_size = AUTOTUNE)

print(dataset["train"])
print(dataset["val"])
```

Now I wanted to use a **weighted version** of `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` for my model and I found [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation), which is rather similar to the example above.
However, they also offered a weighted version of the loss, using:

```
def add_sample_weights(image, label):
  # The weights for each class, with the constraint that:
  #     sum(class_weights) == 1.0
  class_weights = tf.constant([2.0, 2.0, 1.0])
  class_weights = class_weights/tf.reduce_sum(class_weights)

  # Create an image of `sample_weights` by using the label at each pixel as an 
  # index into the `class weights` .
  sample_weights = tf.gather(class_weights, indices=tf.cast(label, tf.int32))

  return image, label, sample_weights
```

and

```
weighted_model.fit(
    train_dataset.map(add_sample_weights),
    epochs=1,
    steps_per_epoch=10)
```

**I combined those approaches** since the latter tutorial uses previously loaded data, while I want to draw the images from disc (not enough RAM to load all at once).

Resulting in the code from the first example (long code block above) followed by

```
def add_sample_weights(image, segmentation_mask):
  class_weights = tf.constant(inv_weights, dtype = tf.float32)
  class_weights = class_weights/tf.reduce_sum(class_weights)
  sample_weights = tf.gather(class_weights,
                             indices = tf.cast(segmentation_mask, tf.int32))
  return image, segmentation_mask, sample_weights
```

(`inv_weights` are my weights, an array of 30 float64 values) and

```
 model.fit(dataset["train"].map(add_sample_weights),
                     epochs = 45, steps_per_epoch = np.ceil(N_img/bs),
                     validation_data = dataset["val"],
                     validation_steps = np.ceil(N_val/bs),
                     callbacks = cllbs)
```

When I run
`dataset["train"].map(add_sample_weights).element_spec`
as in the second example, I get an output that looks reasonable to me (similar to the one in the example):

```
Out[58]: 
(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 512, 512, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(None, 512, 512, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(None, 512, 512, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))
```

However, when I try to fit the model or run something like

```
a, b, c = dataset["train"].map(add_sample_weights).take(1)
```

I will receive the error mentioned above.

So far, I have found quite some questions regarding this error (e.g., [a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60545512/11611246), [b](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68062029/11611246), [c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60480806/11611246), [d](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23698)), however, they all talk of "embedding layers" and things I am not aware of using.

Where does this error come from and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picture `tf.gather` as a fancy way to do indexing. The error you get is akin to the following example in python:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3]
>>> my_list[3] 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If you want to use `tf.gather`, then the range of value of your `indices` should not be bigger than the dimension size of the Tensor you are willing to index.

In your case, in the call `tf.gather(class_weights,indices = tf.cast(segmentation_mask, tf.int32))`, with `class_weights` being a Tensor of dimension `(30,)`, the range of values of `segmentation_mask` should be between 0 and 29. As far as I can tell from your data pipeline, `segmentation_mask` has a range of value between 0 and 255. The fix will be problem dependent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The problem was that the masks had one value higher than the length of the weights (they range from 0 to 30). This was not a place where I would have searched for the error.